# Why always refuse minimum edits lengths?

Tags: feature-request, editing, suggested-edits

After I edited [Does the probable heat of nanotech universal constructors make it infeasible in home environments?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/54548/does-the-probable-heat-of-nanotech-universal-constructors-make-it-infeasible-in/54558#54558) I noticed that the editor had altered 10^12 to 1012. While trying to fix this the editor told me I needed to change at least 6 characters before I could save the edit. In this case I had to make some other trivial changes before I could save it. I understand that normally making only a change of a couple characters probably means the edit is not worth making, but in this case there is a big difference between 10^12 and 1012.

Maybe you should ask a confirmation question on short edits, or just rely on the editing queue to get rid of trivial edits rather than banning them entirely.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that each of your edit has to go through a review process. Where it needs to be reviewed by at least two users. To avoid too many processes, substancial edits are required.

You might comment on the post, to ask someone to edit it. Users with higher reputation are not subject to the same limitation.

<sub>And on that note, I hate the rendering of LaTeX on the edit review, I had the impression that the 10^12 was made with it.</sub>

Comment: I think that's an important point here, any user with sufficient rep to not need the review process can make small edits like this without needing a minimum edit size.

Comment: This is the answer. Mark, once you get to [2,000 rep](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit), you will be able to make small edits. In the meantime, either find something else about the post that you feel can be improved, or add a comment pointing out the problem and let someone else fix it. *Do not flag the post;* factual errors are not flag-worthy problems with a post, so such a flag is likely to be declined.